# Transition of added element with position absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this problem: I append a div into a div at 50px top then try to animate to 0px but the animation never works, even if the div is moved to 0%.

Here is the very simple code

**HTML**

```
<div id="toto"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#toto').append('<div id="test" class="test">test</div>');
$('#test').css('top', '0px');
```

**CSS**

```
#toto{
  display:block;
}
.test{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  transition:all 3s;
  top:50px;
}
```

**FIDDLE**

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/nb0fty1b/)

Any idea how to have it move with CSS transitions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS is being applied too fast for the top change to trigger the transition. You can wrap the class change in a fast `setTimeout()` https://jsfiddle.net/nb0fty1b/1/

```js
$('#toto').append('<div id="test" class="test">test</div>');
setTimeout(function() {
 $('#test').css('top', '0px');
},100);
```

```css
#toto{
  display:block;
  min-height:200px;
}
.test{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  transition:all 3s;
  top:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toto">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the `top` on page load like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#test').css('top', 0);
},2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with CSS `animation` and  `@keyframes`.

```js
$('#toto').append('<div id="test" class="test">test</div>');
```

```css
#toto {
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  animation: move 3s forwards;
}
@keyframes move {
  to {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="toto"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks I really like this solution but min-height and position relative I like less

Comment: @Eric You have min-height set in your fiddle, position relative is important without that the absolute div only relatives to the viewport, i'm sure the real page isn't that simple as the example.

Comment: Sorry, I did try with min-height but forgot to remove it.. Anyway, thanks for your time, really appreciated

Comment: @Eric No problems, a quick demo without position relative https://jsfiddle.net/4h3290v1/